# jQuery Sortable and Bootstrap 3 - works on small device, doesn't work on large device

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery Sortable (http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) and Bootstrap 3.

I'm trying to sort rows in my form, I came up with this code:

```
 $("#timeline_list").sortable({
     handle: 'i.fa',
     onDrop: function (item, container, _super) {
         var data = $('#timeline_list').sortable("serialize").get();
         var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data, null, ' ');

         console.log(jsonString);
         _super(item, container)
     }


 });
```

CSS:

```
.accordion-toggle:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
    content:"\e114";
    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
    float: right;
    /* adjust as needed */
    color: grey;
    /* adjust as needed */
    cursor: pointer;
}
.accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content:"\e080";
    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}
.timeline_name {
    height: 40px!important;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 19px!important;
    width: 95%!important;
}
#timeline_list .accordion-toggle:after {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.dragged {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 2000;
}
#timeline_list li.placeholder {
    position: relative;
    /** More li styles **/
}
#timeline_list li.placeholder:before {
    position: absolute;
    /** Define arrowhead **/
    content:"";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    top: -4px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: red;
    border-right: none;
}
#events ul, #events li, #timeline li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none!important;
}
```

I created following jsfiddle, with the HTML markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/9UA2B/

The sorting works as needed on small devices, but on large screen doesn't work - the position of the element is calculated wrong.

How can I fix that?

EDIT: I created a more readable jsfiddle to demonstrate this issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/9qsxZ/

Comment: If you don't find an answer here, you can try posting this question on the github issue tracker for the project: https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable/issues

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I had `col-md-12` class on the `li`, that was being sorted. After removing it, everything works fine...